# List the last name, salary, and department name of all employees who work on the ‘Computerization’ project

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
SELECT Lname, Salary, Dname
FROM EMPLOYEE 
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT ON DNO = DNUMBER  
INNER JOIN WORKS_ON ON SSN = ESSN 
INNER JOIN PROJECT ON PNUMBER = PNO
WHERE PNAME='COMPUTERIZATION'
```

I tried this but it shows no output. Not sure where exactly I'm wrong.

Link to db:
https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xhEj2sAgdTMABBkCtJvmoC/0#&togetherjs=Dv0FGDGziv

Comment: I would strongly recommend that when using multiple tables in your query, you prefix all your columns with the table name (or table prefix). You'll save yourself some headaches down the line when you're looking at this query later and trying to figure out which columns belong to which tables.

Answer (score 0):

Your Postgres is configured for case-sensitive comparison.  So, you need to use the exact string:

```
where p.pname = 'Computerization'
```

I strongly encourage you to use table aliases and qualified column names as well.